# Mod tags look all funny

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design, meta

Something changed and now the mod-tags on meta look weird.

Fix it?

[image: Buggy tags]

Comment: It's the `a.post-tag, span.post-tag`'s CSS.  `position: relative`, to be exact.

Comment: Look weird for me too.

Comment: Huh, I noticed it too, I just assumed it was `[status-by-design]`. Didn't we raise an issue after the major CSS update that mod-tags were hard to read?

Comment: should point out it's the same with the Regular Tags, when you hover over them they fill with gray but there is that little white bit in the front which looks kinda off. with the Mod Tags when you hover over them they fill with red so it looks ok at that point. when you hover over one of the required tags (the grey ones) they only gain a shadow, no change in color. i assume that maybe this was oversight in the design? thinking that because the required tags look perfect so too would every other tag

Comment: I am also tempted to edit [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xhy7dXWjpAA) in but not sure if it's that urgent for the OP to have it fixed to warrent the clip's use

Answer (score 3):

Arqade no longer has tags that look like the bullets in the question's screenshot, and the red/mod tags style has been tweaked so the border around the tags is less thick and bold, eg:

- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

This happened as part of the Stack Exchange Network-wide [standardised site design rollout](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/179041):

> ...there are several things that will now be standardized to follow the look and feel on Stack Overflow...
>
> Standardized items will include:
>
> - Navigation
> - Fonts
> - Buttons/Icons
> - Tags
> - Newsletter ads

Arqade's site design rollout was announced/discussed [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13097/28182).

Comment: Bullets? I thought they were batteries.

Comment: Well, 'Bullet casings' is a probably more accurate description than just 'bullets' but yeah, I'm pretty sure I recall reading somewhere that's what they were supposed to be, but I could be completely wrong on that front!

Answer (score 1):

If we're looking for consistency with the other tags, the mod tags have the background color of: `#ffecec`

```
.post-tag.moderator-tag {
  color: #c2787a;
  background-color: #ffecec;
}
```

The `::before` is where the issue lies:

```
a.moderator-tag:before, span.moderator-tag:before {
  background-color: #ad150d; <-- this Red - should match above #ffecec;
  border-color: #ad150d;  
}
```

**Produces:**

<kbd>[image]</kbd>